# dynamic function in twig template

Tags: symfony

I would like to display some dynamic text on many twig-templates. 
Instead of adding this variable to every Action , I would prefer to write it once and somehow add it to the templates like

```
{{ displaytext('ann') }}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a Twig Extension class.

Read more about this at http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: That would create a filter. Would it not be more useful to create Service instead?

Comment: to complete your answer you need to add a simple code example.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a file with this variable and include it in the others files -> [Twig includes](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html)

You can set variables for your included page as shown in the documentation:

```
{# template.html will have access to the variables from the current context and the additional ones provided #}
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}

{% set vars = {'foo': 'bar'} %}
{% include 'template.html' with vars %}
```